# Break a for loop with if condition from single line into multiple lines

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, lambda, conditional-statements

I am really confused with this part of the code:

```
newip = []
c = Counter()
for key, group in groupby(logfile, key=lambda e: e.split('.',1)[0]):
   for entry in group:
      c.update(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', entry))
   newip.extend(ip for ip, cnt in c.items() if cnt > 10)
```

How to break these two lines into multiple lines, while doing the same task?

```
for key, group in groupby(logfile, key=lambda e: e.split('.',1)[0]):
...
   newip.extend(ip for ip, cnt in c.items() if cnt > 10)
```

logfile:

```
12/30-04:09:41.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**] [classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.232.2:41676 -> 192.168.248.2:21
12/30-04:09:41.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**] [classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.232.2:41673 -> 192.168.248.2:21
```

Now, I have two questions:

1. Please explain what these two lines exactly do.
2. How to break them into multiple lines, while carrying the same task?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 not available

Comment: If this is from a book, I believe that's where you will find the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line

```
newip.extend(ip for ip, cnt in c.items() if cnt > 10)
```

does

```
for ip, cnt in c.items() 
    if cnt > 10:
       #newip.extend( [ip] ) # with [ ]
       newip.append( ip ) # without [ ]
```

---

Line

```
for key, group in groupby(logfile, key=lambda e: e.split('.',1)[0]):
```

does (but probably `groupby` creates list of tuples `(key, group)` and I use dictinary)

```
groups = groupby(logfile, key=lambda e: e.split('.',1)[0])

for key, group in groups.items():
```

and this I will be guessing

```
groups = dict()

for element in logfile:
    key = element.split('.',1)[0]
    if key not in groups:
       groups[key] = []
    groups[key].append(element)

for key, group in groups.items():
```

Comment: can you explain the split('.',1)[0]? what is the role of '.' , 1 and [0] here?

I have included the logfile in the question which this program reads

Comment: try `print( "192.168.0.1".split('.', 1) )`  and `print( "192.168.0.1".split('.', 1)[0] )` and you will see.

Comment: perfect. but still I have doubt furas, I want to split based on the last occurrence of logfile as well as extract the last string, if cnt>100. I know using rsplit() but it gives error that list doesn't have 'split' attribute.

Comment: you have `rslit()` and `[-1]`

Comment: correction: `rsplit()` (`r` means `right` because it does from right to left)